# Using a lambda expression for multiple columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have this data:

[image]

I want to make a new column where if we have an 'X' in delinquency or Suspect LTV has a 'LTV < 10%' Then I will have a 'Yes' in an entry in a new column.

Example of what the output should look like using this data:

[image]

Now if there is no X and no LTV < 10% then I will just have a 'No'. I am going to be applying this across many columns but I just focused on two to not make it more complicated.

This is what I have tried:

```
def exceptions(column):
    for i in column:
        if i == 'X':
            return 'Yes'
        elif i == 'LTV < 10%':
            return 'Yes'
        else:
            return 'No'


df1['Exceptions'] = df1.apply(lambda x : exceptions(x['Delinquency 2+ Month Change']), axis = 1)
df1['Exceptions'] = df1.apply(lambda x : exceptions(x['Suspect LTV']), axis = 1)
```

Comment: Don't need a `for loop` for this, use: `df1['Exceptions'] = np.where(df1['Delinquency 2+ Month Change'].eq('X') | df1['Suspect LTV'].eq('LTV < 10%', 'Yes', 'No')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that isn't working is because your "exceptions" function needs /both/ columns in order to make a decision, and you're only passing it one of those columns. Instead, you can pass the entire row to your lambda function, and index the columns you need within that function.

```
def exceptions(row):
    if row['Delinquency 2+ Month Change'] == 'X':
        return 'Yes'
    if row['Suspect LTV'] == 'LTV < 10%':
        return 'Yes'
    return 'No'


df1['Exceptions'] = df1.apply(exceptions, axis = 1)
```

I changed your exceptions function to accept one entire row instead of a single cell. There was no need to have a for loop inside it. I  also changed how you call the apply function. This new code is essentially the same as `df1.apply(lambda x : exceptions(x), axis = 1)`, but you don't need to use `lambda` if you're passing your data directly to a function and using the result.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't iterate over the rows of a dataframe for tasks like this (and `apply` is just another way of iterating).

You can do simple boolean arithmetic and apply the result to `where`:

---

*mcve:*

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('xx x '), 'B': list('y y  ')})

df['check'] = 'yes'
df.check.where((df.A=='x') | (df.B=='y'), 'no', inplace=True)

#    A  B check
# 0  x  y   yes                                              
# 1  x      yes                                                   
# 2     y   yes                                              
# 3  x      yes                                              
# 4          no
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Erfan mention in the comment section, you don't really need a for loop or `lambda` to achieve this, You need `np.where`.

1. One way with **`np.where`**
2. Or you can use **`np.where`** with **`np.logical_or`**

### DataFrame:

```
>>> df
  Delinquency 2+ Month Change Suspect LTV
0                           X
1                           X
2                           X
3                           X
4                           X
5                           X   LTV < 10%
```

### Result:

1-  Use OR operator as pipe **`|`**  with **`np.where`**

```
>>> df['Exceptions'] = np.where((df['Delinquency 2+ Month Change'] == 'X') |  (df['Suspect LTV'] == 'LTV < 10%'), 'Yes', 'No')
>>> df
  Delinquency 2+ Month Change Suspect LTV Exceptions
0                           X                    Yes
1                           X                    Yes
2                           X                    Yes
3                           X                    Yes
4                           X                    Yes
5                           X   LTV < 10%        Yes
```

2- Second method as i mention at the start with **`np.where`** with **`np.logical_or`**

```
>>> df['Exceptions'] = np.where(np.logical_or(df['Delinquency 2+ Month Change'] == 'X', df['Suspect LTV'] == 'LTV < 10%'), 'yes', 'no')
>>> df
  Delinquency 2+ Month Change Suspect LTV Exceptions
0                           X                    yes
1                           X                    yes
2                           X                    yes
3                           X                    yes
4                           X                    yes
5                           X   LTV < 10%        yes
```

Same but alternative with `.eq` rather `==`

```
df['Exceptions'] = np.where(np.logical_or(df['Delinquency 2+ Month Change'].eq('X') ,df['Suspect LTV'].eq('LTV < 10%')), 'Yes', 'No')
```

OR

```
df['Exceptions'] = np.where(np.logical_or(df['Delinquency 2+ Month Change'].eq('X') ,df['Suspect LTV'].eq('LTV < 10%')), 'Yes', 'No')
```

In case, you are interested about the way with using defining a function and applying that across ..

Function definition...

```
def exceptions(row):
  if row['Delinquency 2+ Month Change'] == 'X':
    return 'Yes'
  if row['Suspect LTV'] == 'LTV < 10%':
    return 'Yes'
  else:
    return 'No'
```

Use the Function with `DataFrame.apply()` as follows..

```
df['Exceptions'] = df.apply(exceptions, axis=1)
print(df)
  Delinquency 2+ Month Change Suspect LTV Exceptions
0                           X                    Yes
1                           X                    Yes
2                           X                    Yes
3                           X                    Yes
4                           X                    Yes
5                           X   LTV < 10%        Yes
```